# echo PHP messages inside a table cell on the same page

Tags: php

Hi I put a sample code I've done below to explain my concern. Simply the code works fine except displaying the 'echo' messages in a desired location on the page. when the code is executed, the echo messages appear just on the page, but I need the message to be appear in the 'cell4' table cell.

I tried modifying the code as {echo "Name is blank!"; return false;} on the line 30, but seems that its not a correct method as no change in the result. Can someone please tell me is there a workaround for this? Thanks for looking.

Here goes the code:

```
    <html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">User detail</td>
</tr>
</thead>

<tr>
    <td id="cell1">Name:</td>
    <td id="cell2"><input type="text" name="Uname"></td>
    <td id="cell3"><input type="submit" name="SendNow" value="Save"></td>
    <td id="cell4"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['SendNow']))
{
$nm = $_POST['Uname'];

    if($nm == "")
        {echo "Name is blank!"; return false;}
    else
        {echo "Well done!"; return false;}
}       

?>

Sorry the edited code has not appeared correct in the above text. This is how I have tried modifying : {echo "<td id='cell4'>Name is blank!</td>"; return false;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['SendNow']))
{
$nm = $_POST['Uname'];
    $message = '';
    if($nm == "")
        {$message = "Name is blank!";}
    else
        {$message = "Well done!";}
}       

?>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">User detail</td>
</tr>
</thead>

<tr>
    <td id="cell1">Name:</td>
    <td id="cell2"><input type="text" name="Uname"></td>
    <td id="cell3"><input type="submit" name="SendNow" value="Save"></td>
    <td id="cell4"><?php if (!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is inserted into the spot of the document where you execute the code. That means you need to do your processing more like this:

```
<?php

if (isset yada yada)
    $cell_value = ...
}
?>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $cell_value ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

PHP will not "reach back" and change something that's already been output.

Comment: Yes Marc! This is the way to go. Thank You!